# How to declare experimental global variables in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, declare

I need to use the EyeDropper API in my TypeScript project. TypeScript compiler doesn't know anything about this API, so I declared it myself:

```js
interface ColorSelectionResult {
    sRGBHex: string;
}

interface ColorSelectionOptions {
    signal: AbortSignal;
}

declare class EyeDropper {
    open(options?: ColorSelectionOptions): Promise<ColorSelectionResult>;
}

export default EyeDropper;
```

It works great, however I'm not sure how to properly check if this API is handled by the browser in the runtime:

```js
if (typeof EyeDropper === "function") {
    // EyeDropper is available
}
```

This would work, but I'd need to remember about the check. Instead, I'd prefer the TypeScript engine remember that it's either a class, or `undefined`. I tried to create a type:

```js
type EyeDropper = EyeDropperClass | undefined;

export default EyeDropper;
```

But then, I can't use this type to explicitly check if EyeDropper is available. I tried this:

```js
if (window.EyeDropper === "function") {
    // Property 'EyeDropper' does not exist
    // on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.ts(2339)
}
```

Instead, this would work:

```js
if ("EyeDropper" in window) {
    // EyeDropper is available
}
```

But this time, it's a little hacky and I'd prefer to do the check via type, not string.

How should it be done in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Typescript, `typeof` operator is used for values - not really meant for types.

The best way of going about this is to use type augmentation to add new property to the `Window` interface. This means that the property would have the type of `EyeDropper` or `undefined`, meaning that the API may or may not exist.

In the global type definition file (typically named `globals.d.ts`), you can add:

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        EyeDropper?: EyeDropper;
    }
}
```

With your actual code, you can use a type-guard function to check if the EyeDropper API exists:

```
function isEyeDropperAvailable(): window.EyeDropper is EyeDropper {
    return typeof window.EyeDropper === "function";
}

if (isEyeDropperAvailable()) {
    // EyeDropper is available
}
```

Comment: Is `typeof` used at all by TypeScript other than for type narrowing? It's a regular JavaScript operator. To be honest, I was surprised to find out that it worked with my class declaration. It normally throws errors when used with types.

Comment: @RoboRobok check the post again

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna accept your answer, but can you delete the part about `typeof`? It's offtopic.

Comment: @RoboRobok - gonna leave it here for reference: The operator in TS works similarly to JS counterpart in that its primarily used to get the type of the value. But with typescript extends the use of `typeof` to enable some static type operations as well. It helps with dealing with complex type management.